# How can I create Task when right click on the app?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have seen that there are UWP and desktop applications that have shortcuts.
How could you create shortcuts like that?
[Tasks in Calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGFVJ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're referring to jumplists. When you add an item using the [jumplist](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.StartScreen.JumpList?view=winrt-19041#examples) class it will show up when the app is right clicked. Then you just handle the app launch from the jumplist menu item to perform what you need. The windows uwp sample by microsoft for this is straight forward and can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/JumpList).